# Escape a dollar sign inside a variable

Tags: perl

I have a simple line of Perl

```
s/$var/'string'/g
```

The issue is that $var contains a string like `jkdlsf$lkjl`. Note the dollar sign in the middle. It seems because of this dollar sign the replace is not working. How do I escape this when it is inside a variable?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `\Q` quote:

```
s/\Q$var/'string'/g
```

Comment: Exactly. ) Here's quite [a helpful article](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1496) about it.

Comment: @raina77ow pity the link is broken. I came here by searching for the meaning of `\Q`. Any other explanation available?

Comment: That "helpful article" is [Understand the order of operations in double quoted contexts](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/01/understand-the-order-of-operations-in-double-quoted-contexts/)

Answer (score 5):

Use `quotemeta` or the `\Q` and `\E` embedded regex constructs:

```
s/\Q$var\E/'string'/g;

# or

my $var = quotemeta 'jkdlsf$lkjl';
s/$var/'string'/g;
```

Comment: yeah this explains quite well and work perfectly. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape them with backslashes: `$var=~s/\$/\\\$/g`

Comment: does not answer my question.

Comment: @evolution Your question was "How do I escape this when it is inside in a stored variable?" and the above answer tells you exactly that.

Comment: Use `\Q...\E` if you want nothing in $var to be interpreted. Use the above method if you want just `$`s to be escaped, but other characters to keep their special status. If you're after something else then I'm afraid I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: This solution will also modify the contents of `$var`, a side effect that is not necessarily acceptable depending on the situation.